# Getting run() got an unexpected keyword argument 'matrics' on trying to fit neural network using Keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I was following [this](https://machinelearningmastery.com/handwritten-digit-recognition-using-convolutional-neural-networks-python-keras/) tutorial to recognize handwritten digits using the MNIST dataset. There might be some issue based on the Keras, Tensorflow version.

I am getting the following error.

**ERROR**

```
Train on 60000 samples, validate on 10000 samples
Epoch 1/10
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-99-50a245094171> in <module>()
      2 model = baseline_model()
      3 # Fit the model
----> 4 model.fit(X_train, y_train, validation_data=(X_test, y_test), epochs=10, batch_size=200, verbose=2)
      5 # Final evaluation of the model
      6 scores = model.evaluate(X_test, y_test, verbose=0)

~/Documents/Education/Personal/mnist_cnn/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/models.py in fit(self, x, y, batch_size, epochs, verbose, callbacks, validation_split, validation_data, shuffle, class_weight, sample_weight, initial_epoch, steps_per_epoch, validation_steps, **kwargs)
    963                               initial_epoch=initial_epoch,
    964                               steps_per_epoch=steps_per_epoch,
--> 965                               validation_steps=validation_steps)
    966 
    967     def evaluate(self, x=None, y=None,

~/Documents/Education/Personal/mnist_cnn/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py in fit(self, x, y, batch_size, epochs, verbose, callbacks, validation_split, validation_data, shuffle, class_weight, sample_weight, initial_epoch, steps_per_epoch, validation_steps, **kwargs)
   1667                               initial_epoch=initial_epoch,
   1668                               steps_per_epoch=steps_per_epoch,
-> 1669                               validation_steps=validation_steps)
   1670 
   1671     def evaluate(self, x=None, y=None,

~/Documents/Education/Personal/mnist_cnn/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py in _fit_loop(self, f, ins, out_labels, batch_size, epochs, verbose, callbacks, val_f, val_ins, shuffle, callback_metrics, initial_epoch, steps_per_epoch, validation_steps)
   1204                         ins_batch[i] = ins_batch[i].toarray()
   1205 
-> 1206                     outs = f(ins_batch)
   1207                     if not isinstance(outs, list):
   1208                         outs = [outs]

~/Documents/Education/Personal/mnist_cnn/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py in __call__(self, inputs)
   2473         session = get_session()
   2474         updated = session.run(fetches=fetches, feed_dict=feed_dict,
-> 2475                               **self.session_kwargs)
   2476         return updated[:len(self.outputs)]
   2477 

TypeError: run() got an unexpected keyword argument 'matrics'
```

**CODE**

```
import numpy
from keras.datasets import mnist
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.layers import Dropout
from keras.utils import np_utils
from keras import regularizers
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

(X_train, y_train), (X_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()

# flatten 28*28 images to a 784 vector for each image
num_pixels = X_train.shape[1] * X_train.shape[2]
X_train = X_train.reshape(X_train.shape[0], num_pixels).astype('float32')
X_test = X_test.reshape(X_test.shape[0], num_pixels).astype('float32')

# normalize inputs from 0-255 to 0-1
X_train = X_train / 255
X_test = X_test / 255

# one hot encode outputs
y_train = np_utils.to_categorical(y_train)
y_test = np_utils.to_categorical(y_test)
num_classes = y_test.shape[1]

# Define the baseline model here
def baseline_model():
    # Create model
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Dense(num_pixels, input_dim=num_pixels, kernel_initializer='normal', activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(num_classes, kernel_initializer='normal', activation='softmax'))
    # Compile model
    model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', matrics=['accuracy'])
    return model

# build the model
model = baseline_model()
# Fit the model
model.fit(X_train, y_train, validation_data=(X_test, y_test), epochs=10, batch_size=200, verbose=2)
# Final evaluation of the model
scores = model.evaluate(X_test, y_test, verbose=0)
print("Baseline Error: %.2f%%" % (100-scores[1]*100))
```

Comment: matrics = metrics

Comment: Well.... @Aijo has answered your question precisely, I guess.... look at the typo in your code.

Comment: @Ajjo this is embarrassing. I thought it was some high-level stuff, and didn't focus on the typo. My Bad. Thanks